# Undefined method `downcase' when using Soulmate and Redis for Autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

I'm trying to make a `text_field_tag` auto-complete for products. To do this I'm using [Soulmate](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://github.com/seatgeek/soulmate&ei=VGcWU8mVA4H70AGsv4GAAQ&usg=AFQjCNFlcQUwpTOo8cr93TEA80emr3pVYg&sig2=myH-sIQHC8fOj6WfKIxxvg) and followed this [tutorial](http://vincentpaca.github.io/2013/06/09/superfast-search-on-rails-with-soulmate/) but ran into problems after implementing the code and changing it towards my application. The soulmate server does run correctly when I go to `localhost:3000/sm`. Now my code is this:

**Product Model**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :add_to_soulmate
  before_destroy :remove_from_soulmate

  def self.search(name)
    products = Soulmate::Matcher.new("product").matches_for_term(name)
    products.collect { |p| { "id" => p["id"], "name" => p["term"] } }
  end

  private

  def add_to_soulmate
    loader = Soulmate::Loader.new('product')
    loader.add('term' => name, 'id' => self.id)
  end

  def remove_from_soulmate
    loader = Soulmate::Loader.new('product')
    loader.remove('id' => self.id)
  end
end
```

**Product Controller**

```
def autocomplete
  render :json => Product.search(params['name'])
end
```

**Products.js.coffee**

```
$(document).on "keypress", "#search-input", ->
  $("#product-results").html("")

  $.get "/products/autocomplete",
    name: $("#search-input").val(),
    ((data) ->
      count = 0

      while count <= data.length - 1
        product = data[count]
        $("#product-results").append("<li id='product-#{ product.id }'> #{ product.name } </li>")
        count++
    ), "json"
```

**Routes**

```
  resources :products do
    collection do
      get 'autocomplete'
    end
  end

  mount Soulmate::Server, :at => '/sm'
```

**Products/Index View**

```
<div id='product-results'>
  <%= text_field_tag :product_name, nil, autocomplete_off: 'off', id: 'search-input' %>
</div>
```

In the view when I type in a product the whole field just **disappears** completely and if I look at the server log, it has the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass:
```

This same error appears when I go to: localhost:3000/products/autocomplete

So, I'm lost, what can I do?

**EDIT**

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass:
  soulmate (1.0.0) lib/soulmate/helpers.rb:17:in `normalize'
  soulmate (1.0.0) lib/soulmate/matcher.rb:8:in `matches_for_term'
  app/models/product.rb:31:in `search'
  app/controllers/products_controller.rb:5:in `autocomplete'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:423:in `_run__784868843__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__747342270__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/sendfile.rb:105:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:572:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:666:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:521:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.8.2) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
  unicorn-rails (1.1.0) lib/unicorn/rails.rb:24:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:84:in `start'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
  railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `require'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: can you add the full stacktrace as nothing depicts where downcase is being called in your question

Comment: @bjhaid OK, I did it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't sending a String to Soulmate. In your product model in your `search` method around line 31, check to see if your `name` is nil.

Using the `pry` [gem](https://github.com/pry/pry) will help with this.

As per the comment, visit `localhost:3000/products/autocomplete?name=somesearchterm` and see if the error still occurs, as this should ensure you have a valid name.

You probably want to do a check for an empty string to ensure this problem doesn't happen in the future:

*Products Controller*

```
def autocomplete
  name = params['name'] 
  if name.present?
    render :json => Product.search(name)
  else
    render :json => {}
  end
end
```

You also need to provide the front end with data, just like in the tutorial:

In the javascript:

```
while count <= data.length - 1
        contact = data[count]
        $("#contact-results").append("<li id='contact-#{contact.id}'>#{contact.name} - #{contact-number}</li>")
        count++
```

In the controller:

```
contacts.collect { |c| { "id" => c["id"], "name" => c["term"], "number" => c["data"]["number"], "email" => c["data"]["email"] } }
```

Comment: Even your manual test will need the name param: localhost:3000/products/autocomplete?name=somesearchterm

Comment: If I go to `localhost:3000/products/autocomplete?name=somesearchterm` or `/autocomplete?name=ri` (since I have a product called `Rice`) it will return `[]` for both.

Comment: If I try the above code it returns `null`. So this means the name is `nil` as you guessed?

Comment: You need to ensure that the name is not nil when you pass it to the search method: ``render :json => Product.search(params['name'])``

Comment: You need to provide it with data: ``, "number" => c["data"]["number"], "email" => c["data"]["email"] } `` otherwise the front end has nothing to display. See updated answer.